# Using Optmi to fit a quadrtic function

Tags: r, function, optimization, parameters, distribution

I need to fit a quadratic function $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ to the data using `optim()`, with a gradient function specified. I have coded the below which works:

```
{r linewidth=80}
load(url("http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~pfreeman/HW_07_Q7.Rdata"),verbose=TRUE)
set.seed(101)
my.fit.fun = function(my.par)
{
  sum(sqrt(abs(my.par[1]*x^2+my.par[2]*x+my.par[3]-y^2)))               
}


my.par = c(0.2,-4,-5) 
gradient=function(my.par){
  c(my.par[1]*2,my.par[2],0)
}

optim.out = optim(my.par,fn=my.fit.fun, gr=gradient, method = "BFGS")


round(optim.out$par,3)
round(optim.out$value,3)

plot(x,y)
lines(x,optim.out$par[1]*x^2+optim.out$par[2]*x+optim.out$par[3])
```

```
Loading objects:
  x
  y
[1]  0.192  0.038 -5.000
[1] 38.785
```

However, the instruction says the gradient is the gradient of the fit metric, not the derivative of $f(x)$, and that the gradient function returns a vector of length three: the partial derivative of the fit metric with respect to $a$, then with respect to $b$, then with respect to $c$.  I am very confused on what the gradient function is really here? I dont think my gr=gradient is correct (even tho my graph seems fine) so please someone advise on that part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would prefer to use Sum of Squares for the function instead of the absolute value. You could do the following:

```
x <- 1:10
y < c(-0.2499211,-4.6645685,-2.6280750,-2.0146818,1.5632500,0.2043376,2.9151158,  4.0967775,6.8184074,12.5449975)

d <- data.frame(x,y)

fun <- function(par, data){
  y_hat <- data$x^2 * par[1] + data$x * par[2] + par[3]
  sum((data$y - y_hat)^2)
}

optim(c(0.2,-4,-5), fun, data = d)
$par
[1]  0.2531111 -1.3135297 -0.6618520

$value
[1] 17.70251

$counts
function gradient 
     176       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Instead of using `optim`, I would use `nls`. Here you just provide the formula. In this case we would have:

```
nls(y~ a * x^2 + b * x + c, d, c(a=0.2, b=-4, c=-5))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ a * x^2 + b * x + c
   data: d
      a       b       c 
 0.2532 -1.3147 -0.6579 
 residual sum-of-squares: 17.7

Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.816e-08
```

Also why start with `0.2,-4, -5` any prior knowledge? If you use 0,0,0 for example in the optim, you would get the `nls` results

EDIT:

Since you want the BFGS method, you could do:

```
fun <- function(par, data){
  y_hat <- data$x^2 * par[1] + data$x * par[2] + par[3]
  sum((y_hat - data$y)^2)
}

grad <- function(par, data){
  y_hat <-  data$x^2 * par[1] + data$x * par[2] + par[3]
  err <- data$y - y_hat
  -2 * c(sum(err * data$x^2), sum(err * data$x), sum(err))
}
 optim(c(0.2,-4,-5), fun, grad,data = d, method = "BFGS")
$par
[1]  0.2531732 -1.3146636 -0.6579553

$value
[1] 17.70249

$counts
function gradient 
      38        7 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```